# How to report requests from JSR223_Sampler with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

Is it possible to have a JSR223_Sampler Script making web requests report those requests in View Results Tree or View Results in Table?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I have a JSR223 Sampler that is executing multiple concurrent requests based on the result of a previous HTTP Request Sampler. I'm trying to report all of the individual requests made by the JSR223 sampler.

Answer (score 0):

There is `SampleResult` shorthand which stands for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance, you can use functions like [setResponseData()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setResponseData-byte:A-), [setResponseCode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setResponseCode-java.lang.String-), [setResponseMessage()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setResponseMessage-java.lang.String-), etc. so these values will be available to the Listeners.

Example code:

```
def httpClient = org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
def httpGet= new org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet("http://example.com")
def response = httpClient.execute(httpGet)

SampleResult.setResponseCode(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() as String)
SampleResult.setResponseMessage(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase())
SampleResult.setResponseData(org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity()))
```

Example output:

[image]

More information on [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. This is close to what I'm looking for, but the difference is that it's a set of requests and I'm trying to generate individual sample results for each request. This page shows how to make multiple requests, but not how to generate multiple sample results. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter/

Comment: [SampleResult.addSubResult()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#addSubResult-org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult-)

Comment: I tried that but no success. Maybe it's losing context within the new runnable() thread?

Comment: Strangely the `SampleResult` class has `setRequestHeaders` method but nothing to set the request body in results tree :(

Comment: Try [setSamplerData()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setSamplerData-java.lang.String-) function. More information on this and other JMeter API shorthands - [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)